# How to design application url related with id when use mongo comparison with RDBMS?

Tags: mongodb, url, url-routing

Suppose there is a web application that shows some videos. I think it is common case when design its url (not API).

`http://myservice.com/videos/{video-id}`

The strategy is fine when use RDBMS implementations because ids are generally very short but, I've struggled against the problem from using MongoDB.

**MySQL case:**
`http://myservice.com/videos/1`

**Mongo case:**
`http://myservice.com/videos/57932d53a1b33ab926ab54b3`

IMHO, it is too long to represent url. I don't want to see like below

`http://myservice.com/videos/57932d53a1b33ab926ab54b3/comments/57932d53a1b33ab926ab54c2`

Do I have to change a way as like representing video's name or number of sort order? Is there a better idea to represent identifier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ids you gave as example look like autogenerated ObjectId values. You can use any values to represent the _id field as long as they are unique within a single collection.

> The field name _id is reserved for use as a primary key; its value
>   must be unique in the collection, is immutable, and may be of any type
>   other than an array. (See the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#field-names))

Another approach is to add a field in readable format to your document for the url forming purpose (and create a unique index for it if needed).